# SQL - Based on YES or NULL value, assign new value AND concatenate new values

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have six unique columns (let's just call them A, B, C, D, E, F) that all have either YES or NULL as the value. In a new column (let's call it NEW) I need to input the column name (A, B, C, D, E, F) if the value is YES. I also need these values to be concatenated, separated by a comma.

I've been playing around with SELECT/CASE/IF/THEN/ELSE statements, but haven't had any success.

Any guidance that can be offered is appreciated.

Comment: can you show an example of data for the `NEW` column?, for instance, if `A` and `D` are `YES` and the rest are `NULL`s

Comment: If A = YES, B = YES, C = NULL, D = NULL, E = YES, F = NULL then the NEW column would equal: A, B, E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(  CASE WHEN A = 'YES' THEN 'A' END,
                ',' + CASE WHEN B = 'YES' THEN 'B' END,
                ',' + CASE WHEN C = 'YES' THEN 'C' END,
                ',' + CASE WHEN D = 'YES' THEN 'D' END,
                ',' + CASE WHEN E = 'YES' THEN 'E' END) NEW
FROM dbo.YourTable
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like I was heading in the right direction, but getting a visual always helps.